# What is Delphi's equivalent to "+=" for adding elements to a set?

Tags: delphi, operators, set, delphi-7

In other languages like C++, there are operators to do a plus-equals or or-equals type of operation to add additional styles/flags. Is there an equivalent in Delphi?

Right now I have some code like:

```
label1.Font.Style := label1.Font.Style + [fsBold];
label2.Font.Style := label2.Font.Style + [fsBold];
```

But I would love, if it is possible, to get that simplified a bit to something more concise without duplicating the label name on both sides of the assignment operator, something along the lines of: `label1.Font.Style += [fsBold];` or `label1.Font.Style := self + [fsBold];`

Can this be done? Or not so much?

Comment: use the 'inc' function - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Inc. Anyway you can not use it on properties.

Comment: For sets, it wouldn't be Inc, it would be the [Include procedure](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Include) with the same problem that it requires a variable.

Comment: For strings, use `Concat(S1, S2, S3, S4...)`

Comment: No, @Jerry, that function doesn't work that way. It doesn't modify any of its arguments, unlike Inc and Include. Furthermore, Concat is no different from the more idiomatic use of repeated `+` operators. (The function used to be more efficient for four or more operands, but that changed around version 5, maybe earlier.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is one of the few cases where I can recommend the `with` statement:

```
with label1.Font do Style := Style + [fsBold];
with label2.Font do Style := Style + [fsBold];
```

Normally, the problem with `with` is that it is unclear what's a member access and what isn't, but if the scope is a single statement in which a single property is used, it's clear enough.

Comment: What happens when `with label2.Font do Style := Style + [fsBold];` is executed repeatedly?

Comment: what you gain is that label.Font isn't resolved twice there

Answer (score 14):

Include is what you're looking for. Unfortunately you run into the problem that Label.Font.Style is a property and must be assigned to and not passed by var. You can do this however:

```
var
  fontStyle: TFontStyles;
begin
  fontStyle := Label1.Font.Style;
  Include(fontStyle, fsBold);
  Label1.Font.Style := fontStyle;
```

Answer (score 11):

Delphi has the Inc function, but it does not work on properties:

```
Inc(a);     // Increment a with 1
Inc(a, 5);  // Increment a with 5
```

If you need to add style to a font often, you can write a procedure:

```
procedure AddStyle(const AFont: TFont; const AStyle: TFontStyles);
begin
  AFont.Style := AFont.Style + AStyle;
end;
```

(With later versions of Delphi you can use class helpers).

Comment: +1, And I just fix your AddStyle method :), also you can add a sanple of use like so  `AddStyle(Label1.Font,  [fsBold]);`

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `TLabel` type and create a method like this:

```
procedure TMyLabel.AddStyle(const AStyle: TFontStyles);
begin
 Self.Font.Style := Self.Font.Style + AStyle;
end;
```

Then you can put the class into a `bpl` package and install it into editor. After that, you can replace all your labels to your customized labels. For large project i would recommend *Notepad++* to replace all your declarations in `.pas` and (**text!**) `.dfm` files. This may sound complicated but it's less than an hour of work. Good luck!

Comment: dont do this, the complexy you introduce to the code is far then worth the extra work. do it in a visitor pattern, (create an external function that accept TLabel and TFontStyles and do the work in a function).

Comment: This is probably one of the worst possible reasons to create a subclass. A simple utility function does the job quite nicely, without interfering with your class hierarchy.